# Redirect subdomain to root domain when accessed via SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to redirect people from entering www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com.
Also I want to force people to use SSL.
For this I wrote two Middleware classes. One to redirect to root domain from a www subdomain:

```
class WwwMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if request.host.starts_with?("www.")
      [301, {"Location" => request.url.sub("//www.", "//")}, self]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  def each(&block)
  end
end
```

The second one to force SSL connection:

```
class ForceSSL
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    if env['HTTPS'] == 'on' || env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'
      @app.call(env)
    else
      [301, {"Location" => req.url.gsub(/^http:/, "https:")}, []]
    end
  end
end
```

This works well, except if I specifically enter https://www.example.com into the URL bar. This seems to enter my app via SSL before the middleware gets executed. I get this message in a browser:

```
This server could not prove that it is www.example.com; its security certificate is from example.com.
```

How can I change this behaviour? I'm using Heroku for production. Are there any GEMs that I do not know of that do just that?

Comment: why not try the same from nginx or apache server configuration.

Comment: Oh I should add this to my post. I'm using heroku for production. Is there a way to do that there?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't used it. But there must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change this behaviour: the browser is trying to connect to https://www.example.com but your certificate is for a different domain. Your application isn't involved at all at this point.

The only way to deal with this would be to have an ssl certificate that is valid for both www.example.com and example.com

Comment: But how does a site like youtube does that for example? If you try typing in a youtube link like https://youtube.com it will redirect you to https://www.youtube.com

Comment: They have a certificate valid for both domains